# Is there any way to save my session in Ubuntu 16.04 (NOT hibernate)?

Tags: unity, 16.04, session

I went through a lot of previous duplicates. But still....

Well ***dconf editor > org > gnome > gnome-session > auto-save-session*** is not working. It doesn't prompt me to save during log off/reboot. On reboot my apps do not load start like before.

Is there any way in 16.04? or am I doing something wrong here.

Comment: Becomes a problem after I update my system and I feel like rebooting just to get my throat clear....

Comment: did you finally found an orthodox way to do this? the only things I've seen so far are workarounds based on third-party scripts.

Comment: Auto-save-session was removed for security related problems with it and hibernate was a far better alternative. You will need a 3rd party app for this.

Comment: A method: http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/how-to-save-and-restore-unity-session.html

Comment: I wrote a little tool that can do that: https://github.com/johannesjo/linux-window-session-manager

Comment: @hugoderhungrige You should really add that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [little tool that can do that](http://github.com/johannesjo/linux-window-session-manager) and there is also a [gnome-shell-extension](https://github.com/johannesjo/gnome-shell-extension-window-session-manager) that uses it. You can install it via `npm install -g linux-window-session-manager`. Nodejs needs to be installed and on some machines you have to add sudo to the command. Afterwards you can run:

```
lwsm save sessionName
# and
lwsm restore sessionName
```

Note that wayland applications are not included (but XWayland works fine).